# Xcode13 - Legacy Build System deprecated, unable to install to device with New Build System

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13

Legacy Build System has been deprecated since Xcode10+ but can still choose to use it. In the newest xcode Xcode13 you would encounter an error if attempt to use it - [release note reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes)

We were able to get our App build to device using the New Build System but it only works on the initial build. The subsequent builds will encounter a `Unable To Install` error. We find that reopen Xcode, close out simulators, clearing derivedData, Clean Build folder would make the build work again but only once then the "Unable To Install" error would appear again.

Anyone else seeing similar issues in Xcode13? If so, do you have suggestions or workaround?

[image]

Comment: the same issue. I try to change to new build system but I get more than errors.

Comment: Same issue in Xcode 13.1 and 13.2.1. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

This is the new option that needs to be added to WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings file:

1. Right click on ***<<Your_Project>>.xcworkspace*** file and click show package contents
2. open ***xcshareddata*** folder
3. edit ***WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings*** file

```html
<key>DisableBuildSystemDeprecationDiagnostic</key>
    <true/
```

Here's a complete WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings file with both settings (please ignore the unrelated PreviewsEnabled option):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildSystemType</key>
    <string>Original</string>
    <key>DisableBuildSystemDeprecationDiagnostic</key>
    <true/>
    <key>PreviewsEnabled</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Path to the file for flutter project: ios/Runner.xcworkspace/xcshareddata/WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings

Comment: Any idea how this can work for xcodebuild - it just ignores -UseModernBuildSystem=NO now and xcodebuild doesn't consider workspace settings afaik

Comment: To answer my own question if you set the above setting at a project level and pass -UseModernBuildSystem=NO it does then do what you intend.

Answer (score 2):

There should be an option in Xcode 13 to keep using the legacy build system. File-> Workspace Settings -> Check "Don't show a diagnostic issue about build system deprecation" and click done.

Answer (score 1):

If using CLI, you can use the following commands:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :DisableBuildSystemDeprecationDiagnostic bool" WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :DisableBuildSystemDeprecationDiagnostic true" WorkspaceSettings.xcsettings
```

Obviously, find the relevant file for the project to modify.

Comment: No need for two commands, you can "Add :DisableBuildSystemDeprecationDiagnostic bool true"

Answer (score 0):

I have already installed both Apple Development and Distribution certificates in my local `Keychain Access` but I was facing the same problem with you though.

Interestingly, only thing that I changed `Signing(Debug)` option to `Automatically manage signing` and it builded up on my real device finally.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

File -> build system -> new build system.

Comment: Actually works.